# Get Mod Rewrite Redirect to Show Up in Address Bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want `www.grabmegrub.com` to redirect to `www.grabmegrub.com/page/calendar`. At this moment it successfully redirects the user and displays the calendar page, but it does not update the address bar. How do I make the address bar display `www.grabmegrub.com/page/calendar`?

Here's the code, which is located in the .htaccess file of the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ page/calendar
```

[www.grabmegrub.com](http://www.grabmegrub.com) is live. Visit it to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `R` flag at the end of `RewriteRule` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /page/calendar [R]
```

Comment: That did not work. I have no idea why! It really seems like it should.

Comment: @VictordeFontnouvelle Updated the reply above. Please check again.

Comment: I tried it, and it still has the same behavior (updating but not changing the address bar).

Comment: @VictordeFontnouvelle You're putting the code in htaccess in root directory of the site? Any other rules which might conflict? I don't even notice the update of page.

Comment: I removed the rule from the site for the moment because it wasn't working like I wanted it to. No other conflicting rules. I guess I can do without this, although it is pretty annoying

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/calendar$ / [L]
```

It should give your the URL:

`www.grabmegrub.com/page/calendar`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. That redirected the calendar page to the root, whereas what I wanted was to redirect the root to the calendar page.